# How to add my custom menu commad to installed applications in windows 7 and above

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, contextmenu

Actually, I created a simple app in C# which creates a snapshot of the screen and upload to One Drive automatically. But the problem is I need to open my application when i want to do the operation. So, to minimize the effort and enhance the accessibility, am trying to add an extra menu option to the context menu of title bar of all the installed applications. Is there any method to do the same. Please suggest.

[Expected UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH22j.png)

Comment: The OS does not provide an API for this. Is there a reason, why you aren't registering a hotkey, like most (if not all) screenshot tools? Also note that your app really only targets Windows 7 and 8. With Windows 10, that functionality is available in the OS already.

Comment: @IInspectable the OS does have API for that. Otherwise, products like WindowBlinds won't exist. However, that's not for "simple app" in the question.

Comment: @LexLi: There is no API. If you must disagree, provide a link to documentation. Applications like WindowBlinds are notorious examples of software, that break with every update of Windows for the sole reason, that they rely on implementation details of the OS rather than the documented API.

Comment: @LexLi: Spy++ does not add a context menu entry to arbitrary applications. It's unclear to me, how Spy++ is related to any of this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can i acheive this or not :( Please add some reference if any :)